# How to represent the result in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

[image]

I have two fields like above image.

The above three rows to be represented as single row as mentioned in same image.

Can someone let me know how to produce the above result in Hive without using UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws`:

```
select
    concat_ws(',', collect_list(concat_ws(':', col1, col2))) as output
from mytable
```